# Shutdown menu missing from unity indicators

Tags: unity, indicator

I found that I'm missing the shutdown or session indicator, i believe, from my list of indicators.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have the package `indicator-session` installed.